# Enyo.drag implementation on an element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, enyo

Can someone give a simple example program for dragging an element in ENYO framework..
I'm not able to understand the drag library of enyo, as i'm new to this enyo framework..
it would b enough if just include a draggable button in an html page..

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of sample code for drag in Enyo.  According to this article:

http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/752/enyo-drag-implementation-on-an-element

there's some example usage in the Ares 2 codebase:

https://github.com/enyojs/ares-project/blob/master/deimos/source/Deimos.js

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Sorry @Pre101 , I only asked that question there, n couldn't get the answer.. Those are not exactly the drag implementations..